# A website to see the complete list of titles under which the book was published

Tags: title, library-and-information-science

There are many "old" books that are known by different titles. For example, [*La Mule sans frein*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Mule_sans_frein) (English: *The Mule Without a Bridle*), which is also known as *La Demoiselle à la mule* (English: *The Damsel with the Mule*). And some books are known by 3, 4, or even more titles.

Such a variety of titles of the same books makes it difficult to choose the right one to use it in a bibliography. Is there a website where I can (at least!) search for an arbitrary book and then see a complete list of its titles?

Comment: I remember I saw something similar recently, and I even had a thought like "Why is this even needed!!" Now I know :) Unfortunately, I have no idea how to find it again :(

Comment: @virolino Try search the history in your browser :) Ctrl-H for Chrome on Windows or Command-Y if you use Chrome or Safari on Mac.

Comment: I now about that feature, but the needle is small, and the haystack huge. I do not even know I landed on that page, so I have no idea what to look for :( I would be more than happy to help, if I could.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if by "bibliography" you mean "reference section of an academic paper," you should cite the title of the edition that you actually read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/) does this fairly well for books that have been catalogued in the participating libraries (which are mostly academic libraries). I recommend using the advanced search, so you can specify author and title separately.

For [*La Mule sans frein*](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3ALa+Mule+sans+frein), WorldCat gives results in various languages. Since I didn't specify an author, the search also returns publications about the romance and not just editions and translations.
But for [Stevenson's *Strange Case of Dr Jekyll and Mr Hyde*](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=ti%3AStrange+Case+of+Dr+Jekyll+and+Mr+Hyde+AND+au%3AStevenson&limit=10&offset=11), where I included the author's name in the search, I get printed editions and audio versions. The advanced search also allows me to scope the search just to printed books or to a specific language (or both). There is no guarantee that this will return all translations, since that is determined by the catalogues of the participating libraries.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer, the [ISFDB](https://isfdb.org/) does this fairly well for fantasy and science fiction literature, with alternate titles provided for entries. That said, it is limited to SF&F, to the point where story anthologies sometimes don't list non-fantastic stories in the book.